# How To Create A New Array Of First Names From Array Of First And Last Names?

Tags: php, arrays

Hey all. I need to create an array of first names from another array of first and last names.  So basically the original array with first and last names looks like this:

**Original Array**

```
array("John Doe", "Jane Doe", "John Darling", "Jane Darling");
```

And the array I need to create from that would be:

**New Array**

```
array("John", "Jane", "John", "Jane");
```

So I guess for each value I would need to remove whatever comes after the space. If someone can point me in the correct direction to use regular expressions or some array function that would be great.

Cheers!

Update:
Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick, and if it shouldn't I'm really sorry but haven't slept this night :P, but you'll get the idea ;)

```
<?php
    $secondarray=array();
    foreach($firstarray as $fullname){
        $s=explode(' ',$fullname);
        $secondarray[]=$s[0];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a callback function that strips the last names, and map it to the array, like so (I use a different approach rather than `explode()`, both are equally valid methods):

```
function strip_last_name($name) {
    if (($pos = strpos($name, ' ')) !== false) {
        // If there is at least one space present, assume 'first<space>last'
        return substr($name, 0, $pos);
    } else {
        // Otherwise assume first name only
        return $name;
    }
}

$first_names = array_map('strip_last_name', $full_names);
```

This preserves the array keys and the order of elements.

Comment: That would work, but what if they have hyphenated first or last name.

Comment: @422: You mean something like John-Doe? My answer assumes `first<space>last` only.

Comment: sure, or Roger k'inaird, or Taylor Brock-Smith or Sarah-Lee Cakes lol, I havent tested your code, but if it strips characters out inc' spaces, surely it would transcribe the hyphenated word and append it to its link .. so Taylor BrockSmith ? Not sure just thinking outside the rectangle

Comment: @422: My function works just fine for all three, returns Roger, Taylor and Sarah-Lee respectively.

Comment: In that case I will bloody use it, cos I have a serious need for this. Good Onya , voted accordingly :)

Comment: +1 : You can also make only one call to strpos(), searching is slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array("John Doe", "Jane Doe", "John Darling", "Jane Darling");
$array2 = array();
foreach ($array1 as $name) {
    $firstname = explode(' ',$name);
    $array2[] = $firstname[0];
}
```

The `explode` function splits a string by a delimiter, for example `explode('b','aaaaabccccc')` returns `array('aaaaa','ccccc')`. The above code uses this, with a foreach loop, to split each full name into an array containing the first and last name, and then add the first name to an array like the first one.